# Angular + Requirejs - how to return multiple modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, requirejs

How can I return multiple angular modules in requirejs environment?

this is my app.js,

```
define([
    'angular',
    'angular-route',
    'jquery'
], function (ng,ngRoute,$) {
    'use strict';
    console.log($('h1').length);

    return ng.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']); 

});
```

And I need a few more modules to return,

```
ng.module('myAppModule1', ['ngRoute']); 
ng.module('myAppModule2', ['ngRoute']); 
ng.module('myAppModule3', ['ngRoute']);
```

a controller example, for instance I want to get 'myAppModule3' in `app.js`,

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule3');
    myAppModule.controller('welcomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        //your minsafe controller 
        $scope.message = "Message from WelcomeController"; 
    }]);
});
```

Comment: I see you've edited your question back to what it was. That was the right thing to do. Otherwise, you would have had a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). The new issue you were asking about was a *different* problem that called for a *different* question. In brief, you were creating your module twice: once with the `ng-app` directive and once with the `ng.module` call.

Comment: Thanks Louis for the reply! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `app.js` to return an object whose fields are the modules:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'angular-route',
    'jquery'
], function (ng,ngRoute,$) {
    'use strict';
    console.log($('h1').length);

    return {
        myApp: ng.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']),
        myAppModule1: ng.module('myAppModule1', ['ngRoute']), 
        myAppModule2: ng.module('myAppModule2', ['ngRoute']), 
        myAppModule3: ng.module('myAppModule3', ['ngRoute'])
    };
});
```

And change your controller like this:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.myAppModule3.controller('welcomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        //your minsafe controller 
        $scope.message = "Message from WelcomeController"; 
    }]);
});
```

Comment: thanks. but it does not work though. i get an error - `TypeError: app.controller is not a function
 

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {`...

Comment: You have to call `app.myAppModule.controller`, not `app.controller`.

Comment: where did `myAppModule` come from?

Comment: Look at the `return` statement in `app.js`. The module is an object with four fields named `myApp`, `myAppModule1`, `myAppModule2`, and `myAppModule3`.

Comment: Sorry. I made a typo, which carried over into my comment, which I did not see until now. It's `app.myAppModule3` (with the 3) that you need.

Answer (score 1):

The generic (non-Angular specific) way is to use an object:

```
 return {module1: /*..*/, module2: /*...*/ };
```

Then you just access to the values:

```
 define(['app'], function (app) {
    var module1 = app.module1;
 });
```

However in Angular you just registered 'myAppModule1' in the Angular global. There is no need to do the object return, you can retrieve the registered module using the angular object:

```
 define(['angular'], function (angular) {

    var module1 = angular.module('myAppModule1');
    // without extra parameter it tells angular to retrive an existing
    // module
 });
```

**Update:** I just realize that you did it in your code. It didn't worked? Maybe be you have a dependency issue, make sure that `app.js` is loaded first.

Comment: thanks. but i get this error `TypeError: app.controller is not a function
 

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {`....